# How can I programmatically update the fields, like FileName, in the pageheader in an MS Word 2007 document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code only updates the fields outside the page headers.

```
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

I also asked the question on [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/b2f51769-ccaf-4194-921e-820ab6670d4c/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it.

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

Geoffrey's answer did not work for me for some reason.

Eventually I got the fields updated in my footers using a sledgehammer and a stick of dynamite like so:--

```
        wDoc.PrintPreview();
        wDoc.ClosePrintPreview();
```